# Visual Studio 2015 - Manipulating Excel?

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2015

I have 750 Excel files that I want to

1. clean by deleting columns of data that have a heading with an asterisk,
2. then take some of that data and put it in a new workbook worksheet, and other data into the same workbook worksheet, and some other data into a second new workbook.

I created a WPF project in Visual Studio 2015 with a little dialog box with 2 radio buttons for

1. clean data,
2. produce new files.

This is my VB code:

```
    Class MainWindow
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook
    Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim strName As String
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String

    Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
        If cleanRadioButton.IsChecked = True Then
            strPath = "c:\test\old\"
            strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
            Do While strFile <> ""

                wb = wb.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)

                'Loop through the sheets.
                For iIndex = 1 To Application.Worksheets.Count
                    ws = Application.Worksheets(iIndex)

                    'Loop through the columns.
                    For iCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                        'Check row 1 of this column for the char of *
                        If InStr(ws.Cells(10, iCol).Value, "*") > 0 Then
                            'We have found a column with the char of *
                            ws.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
                            ws.Columns(iCol + 1).EntireColumn.Delete
                            ws.Columns(iCol + 2).EntireColumn.Delete
                        End If
                    Next iCol

                Next iIndex
                wb.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\test\new\" & wb.Name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
                wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
                strFile = Dir()
            Loop
            MessageBox.Show("The csv files have now been cleaned.  Congrats.")
        Else inputRadioButton.IsChecked = True
            MessageBox.Show("The data has now been split into Trajectory and ForcePlate input files.  High 5.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**I get 3 errors but can't work out how to solve them**.

a) Worksheets is not a member of Application [line 19]

b) Worksheets is not a member of Application [line 20]

c)  'xlOpenXMLWorkbook' is not declared.  It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: I use both VB.Net and VBA.  VB.Net has a wealth of functionality, including access to workbooks saved under any version of Excel, and the resulting executables **can** be a hundred times faster than a VBA macro.  I consider VB.Net the better language and I use it more than VBA.  However, access to workbooks from VB.Net is slow. If the only objective of a program is to manipulate workbooks, I would use VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a) and b), the pattern is :

> Application.Workbooks.Worksheets

For c), easiest way out :

> Go into VBE from Excel (Alt + F11)
>
> Press F2 to display the Object Browser
>
> Look for xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Result : `Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51 (&H33)`
So, just replace it by the value 51!

---

Here is your amended code :

```
  Class MainWindow
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook
    Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim strName As String
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim wbIndex As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String

    Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
        If cleanRadioButton.IsChecked = True Then
            strPath = "c:\test\old\"
            strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
            Do While strFile <> ""

                wb = wb.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)

                'Loop through the sheets.
                For wbIndex = 1 To Application.Workbooks.Count
                    For iIndex = 1 To Application.Workbooks(wbIndex).Worksheets.Count
                        Ws = Application.Workbooks(wbIndex).Worksheets(iIndex)
    
                        'Loop through the columns.
                        For iCol = 1 To Ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                            'Check row 1 of this column for the char of *
                            If InStr(Ws.Cells(10, iCol).Value, "*") > 0 Then
                                'We have found a column with the char of *
                                Ws.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
                                Ws.Columns(iCol + 1).EntireColumn.Delete
                                Ws.Columns(iCol + 2).EntireColumn.Delete
                            End If
                        Next iCol
    
                    Next iIndex
                Next wbIndex
                'Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51 (&H33)
                wb.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\test\new\" & wb.Name, FileFormat:=51)
                wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
                strFile = Dir()
            Loop
            MessageBox.Show ("The csv files have now been cleaned.  Congrats.")
        Else: inputRadioButton.IsChecked = True
            MessageBox.Show ("The data has now been split into Trajectory and ForcePlate input files.  High 5.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi R3UK - thx for taking the trouble to reply.  I implimented your amended code but although this solved problem c) [thx btw], errors a) and b) persist under the form: ActiveWorkbook is not a member of Application.... any ideas??  thx

Comment: @TomChambers : So `ActiveWorkbook` probably isn't in Visual Studio, so I added a loop on `Workbooks` to avoid using it, the only issue is that this will probably scan all open workbooks, you can add a test on the name or something if you'd like!

Answer (score 1):

To reference a worksheet yau can use either `ws = wb.Worksheets(1)` or `ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")` or `ws = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` and to use `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` use the name of the corresponding Enum `XlFileFormat`as well: `XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook`.

This simplified example opens the workbook *Test.xlsx*, writes text in cell *A1* and saves it to new folder.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim excelApp As Application
        Dim wb As _Workbook
        Dim ws As _Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim strPathOld = "c:\temp\old"
        Dim strPathNew = "c:\temp\new"

        ' get excel application reference
        excelApp = New Application
        excelApp.Visible = True
        excelApp.ScreenUpdating = True

        ' open the workbook
        wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Path.Combine(strPathOld, "Test.xlsx"))

        ' set reference to the sheet with index 1
        ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

        ' or use sheet name
        ' ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' or use ActiveWorkbook if it exists
        ' ws = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        ' write text in cell A1
        rng = ws.Range("A1")
        rng.Formula = "Test123"

        ' save the workbook in new location
        wb.SaveAs(Filename:=Path.Combine(strPathNew, wb.Name), _
              FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)

        excelApp.Quit()

    End Sub
End Class
```

*Note: add reference to MS Office Interop for your version of Excel(here example for Excel 2007).*
[image]

Comment: Hi dee, thanks for taking the time to respond.  I put your code but i keep getting errors that things aren't defined or are not contained in Application ... any ideas??

Comment: @Tom I do not know what the problem is. But see the edited answer, have added a picture how the Excel-Interop dll reference looks like in my sample project. HTH

Comment: Probably the Application type in your code is not Excel-Application? Try to use fullly qualified name, write ```Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application```.